# Why does QGIS not show my new geometry columns?

Tags: qgis, postgis, connection

I am trying to connect a few PostGIS Tables to Quantum GIS.

The problem is that the geometry columns QGIS is showing are not the ones from the PostGIS database. QGIS shows me some columns I used to have before. Newer ones I created later are not shown. So I can't display my actual data.

It seems like QGIS is keeping some old information about my tables. Is there any way to refresh PostGIS connections?

Even deleting the old connections and building new ones does not work.

I checked all the tables on the database level. Everything is alright there. So it seems like a QGIS bug...

Comment: Did you update the geometry_columns table entries when you created the new columns?

Comment: What do you mean by update? I made a copy of an existing table. The copy looks exactly the same on the database (including constraints). QGIS shows me non existing columns (that have been there a while ago), but not the existing geometry columns

Comment: Got it. Using the SQL copy function does not affect the geometry_column needed by PostGIS.

Comment: @Yojimbo could you post what you did when you found out that the geometry_column wasn't copied? I'm having the same problem now